# How to get multi-coloured placeholder text?

Tags: placeholder

long story short,
here's my placeholder text:

`<textarea id="colour" type="text" rows="9" name="message" placeholder="Hi, I'm the next star architect! Here's my work before ever studying for a RIBA1, I first got inspired into doing architecture playing Sims 4 and I instantly had to download Architecture software to build a house. My first project is my Mesuem/Art gallery and I grown massively in that first project. Please look though every project, especially the ones with the star. ... ...Also type here and hit send if you want to email me." ></textarea>`

Hi=ow can I make the 'hi' part colour green or 'sims 4' part yellow without using the span tag,

is it even possible????

many thanks

didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible, and it is not best practices to use placeholder text to hold vital information. It would be much better to put your message around the input field or in a label, style as you wish, and keep placeholder text short and descriptive. Keep in mind not everyone can see your placeholder text and screen readers usually do not announce it.

If you would like more information on placeholder text and accessibility see the WCAG https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/instructions/#placeholder-text